# How to add variable for name of splitted multi tiffs in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, tiff

I have a problem with my xml output from my xslt. The target system cannot recieve multi-tiff image files so i have to split them into singles. The problem is when i split them it names every file with an extension of the page number. So page one gets xxx_001.tif, page 2 gets xxx_002.tif etc. I need to specify the correct name of every image file in my xslt.

The current code i have is created for multitiff imagefiles. Not one for every page.

```
<!-- image file --> 
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Invoice/UserDefinedVariables/UserDefinedVariable[@Name='WebEye.DocumentID']/text(),'-','')"/><xsl:text>.tif,</xsl:text>
<!-- number of pages -->
<xsl:value-of select="System/Field[@Type='NumberOfPagesFrontAndBack']"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<!-- all pages -->
<xsl:value-of select="translate(Invoice/UserDefinedVariables/UserDefinedVariable[@Name='WebEye.DocumentID']/text(),'-','')"/><xsl:text>.tif,</xsl:text>
```

How do i add the page numbers to the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Added a loop to go through the counts.

```
<xsl:template name="writefilenames">
  <xsl:param name="i" />
  <xsl:param name="count" />
  <xsl:param name="docid" />

  <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= $count">

     <xsl:if test="$i &gt;1">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
     </xsl:if>

     <xsl:value-of select="$docid"/>
     <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="format-number($i, '000')"/>
     <xsl:text>.tif</xsl:text>

     <xsl:call-template name="writefilenames">
        <xsl:with-param name="i">
           <xsl:value-of select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="count">
           <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="docid">
           <xsl:value-of select="$docid"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
     </xsl:call-template>
```